# how to enable both two input element has focus at the same time?

Tags: javascript

I have two input elements, when the mouse click the input element, the input element will have focus, and there is a cursor in the input element.

Now I want both of the two int elements can display the cursor, there will be two cursor at the same time.

Can JavaScript do this?

Comment: That sounds not so usefull. What would you achieve? The same data in the two fields?

Comment: By definition only one element may have focus at a time.

Comment: @RaphaelMüller I just want to let the two input elements display cursor at the same time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont think javascript can do this. But if you want one string in two inputbox, you can use keypress event for copying value form active to other.

Comment: yes, I have searched some materials, but it seems that there can only be a focus on elements at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this with the `jQuery` key events 'keyup', you can copy the value of one input box to another, please see this `jsfiddle`. [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/lokeshpahal/m29j6xhh/1/)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#input1').keyup(function(e){
        $('#input2').val($('#input1').val());
    });
});
```

Comment: This is not applying focus to more than one element at a time, merely copying content on an action, i.e. keyup.

Comment: I agree with @JonP. Maybe there is no way to do this.Thank you~